# 3D Touch support for iOS On Codename One

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

Would CodenameOne be able to support different gestures for different platforms? For example, can you take advantage of 3D Touch for iPhone?

Since all platforms have their own gestures, I guess it would be difficult, but it would be interesting to hear what your views on this would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while the gestures are very different within the OS most of the gestures within the apps themselves are very similar at least for iOS/Android/Windows.

There are a few minor things like typing on the title in iOS to scroll up (we support that), swiping back on iOS (we allow you to support that) etc.

Currently we don't support 3d touch although that's totally possible and should be easy. There is [an RFE for that](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1575) I submitted but there was no specific user demand so we didn't get around to doing it.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/WiH8O1jxEGg/fNlOFP4lCAAJ